# Отдельная иконка приложения для бета тесторивания

Tags: android, google-play, apk

увидел что у меня на андроид смартфоне есть приложения, в которых я числюсь бета тестером, и у них лаунч иконка отличается от той, что в релизном. При этом скачены они официально. Захотелось и у себя так сделать, вспомнил что есть activity-alias, и вроде бы все хорошо, но не понятно как узнать является ли пользователь бета тестером, или нет (кроме как сверять через АПИ по имени сборки).

Хотелось бы узнать какие есть механизмы удовлетворяющие мои хотелки. Спасибо заранее!

Comment: бета это же отдельный релиз, кто на бету не подписан, тот бету и не скачает. Поэтому самого пользователя проверять не требуется. Разные иконки можно ставить через flavors в gradle, посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875948/how-to-provide-different-android-app-icons-for-different-gradle-buildtypes

Comment: @Эникейщик у меня в стране есть один банк, у которого есть приложение, так вот я вижу иконку, условно назовем её "Бета", когда скачиваю бета версию, но в день когда они делают ее релизной, иконка сама меняется. Это и запутывает меня)

Comment: т.е. меняется без скачивания нового апк?

Comment: @Эникейщик , я почти что уверен) Как минимум версия, та что публичная, всегда остается одинаковой

Comment: Ну тогда я не знаю, с таким пока не сталкивался